# Installing/running JQ on git bash

Tags: bash, git, curl, installation, jq

I'm trying to implement a git hook that edits some JSON every time I push.
I have JQ installed on my Mac using homebrew "brew install jq", but when the git hook runs my .sh I get the error

```
jq: command not found
```

My latest attempts have been to use curl to download the jq library, point to it, and run jq that way:

```
jq=/usr/local/Cellar/jqz
curl -L -o $jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-osx-amd64
```

Unfortunately, this is also returning the same 'command not found' error.
Sidenote: jq=/usr/bin/jq gives me a permission error when I try to write to it

Comment: A file directly created by `curl` won't have execute permissions unless you use `chmod` to add them.

Comment: BTW, this isn't particularly software-development-specific; you'd have the same problem installing _any_ executable the same way, including one that wasn't a development tool or being used in a development-specific context. As such, I'd consider [apple.se] likely to be a more topical place.

Comment: Anyhow -- make sure the context in which your hook runs has a `PATH` that includes the location with your executable.

Comment: (...I also recommend using Nix instead of Homebrew, but that's an entirely different discussion).

Comment: ...and yes, it's completely normal that you can't write to `/usr/bin` on Catalina and later; that filesystem is locked-down and read-only on current OS releases.

Comment: (also, "git bash" isn't a thing that _exists_ on MacOS, so it's odd to hear you use the term; "Git Bash" is the name for bash _as packaged with Git for Windows_; it doesn't exist on non-Windows platforms, where what you have is just "bash", not "git bash").

Comment: jq=/usr/local/Cellar/jqz
 curl -L -o $jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-osx-amd64
 chmod -x $jq 

bash files are not my wheelhouse, I'm just trying to hack together something to auto-version my project when I commit. 
I'm currently searching for how to use chmod to add this executable...

Comment: `chmod +x jq` makes `jq` be flagged executable. Note that it's `+` not `-` to add (instead of removing) the permission.

Comment: Also, when you're putting code in a comment, be sure you add `;`s as line separators. Lots of things don't work in bash when you leave out command separators (`foo=bar baz` and `foo=bar; baz` -- the latter being the same if you have a newline in place of the `;` -- are both syntactically valid, but they do completely different things)

Comment: As another aside, be sure you quote parameter expansions. `"$jq"`, with the quotes, not just `$jq`. The bugs won't bite you 100% of the time (depends on your data, the current value of IFS, and sometimes what files are in your current directory), but when they do, they can sting.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq=/usr/local/Cellar/jqz
curl -L -o $jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-osx-amd64
```

It looks like you are storing the binary with the name `jqz`. No surprise that it cannot be executed as `jq`; you would have to invoke it as `jqz`.

I don't know if `/usr/local/Cellar` is part of your PATH?

The canonical way would be:

```
jq='/usr/local/bin/jq'
curl -L -o "$jq" https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-osx-amd64
```

you could also store it in the `bin` directory of your home folder: `jq="$HOME/bin" which should be added automatically to your PATH on most installations (might require a logout & login).