# Run jq command in git-bash

Tags: jq, git-bash

[jq command not found after adding jq executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202170/bash-jq-command-not-found-after-adding-jq-execuable-file-to-env-variable)

[installing jq on git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000844/installing-running-jq-on-git-bash)

My usecase is more similar with above shared references. I tried to execute a hook that needs to parse a json file. When hook gets executed it throws **bash: jq:command not found**  error. So. I downloaded jq-win64.exe file and copied it to */usr/bin* in Git folder. Then from git-bash I run **export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/jq-win64.exe"** command and there is no error but when I checked jq --version command it still shows **bash: jq:command not found** error

Am I missing something? I even tried in windows cmd but is of no use. Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Note that git-bash is not part of Git. It is merely a port of bash *to* Windows, and is typically included *with* Git-for-Windows, because Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, and the port of bash was available.

Comment: @torek The Git folder which I referred here is the one that appeared in C drive when I installed git-bash.exec on my system.

Comment: You can install git-bash by itself, or you can install Git-for-Windows which also installs git-bash. It sounds like you did the latter. Git isn't relevant! Just git-bash and jq matter here. (The fact that Git is invoking bash for you, via your hooks, just makes bash matter; the fact that your bash script invokes jq makes jq matter. You can run the hook without using Git.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` contains directories. That means what you should do:

1. Rename `jq-win64.exe` to `jq.exe` or just `jq`. (e.g. `cp ~/Downloads/jq-win64.exe /usr/bin/jq`).
2. You don't have to export your path, `/usr/bin` is already part of it.

If you didn't rename the file to `jq` (or `jq.exe`), then you would have to run it as `jq-win64` in your console.

You could also put the binary into `~/bin` folder, which should be part of PATH too. If it isn't, you can add it. Then you don't need to mess with your global binaries folder.

Comment: @Knitti Thankyou so much. I have no idea of renaming jq-win64.exe file. It worked well!!!

Comment: @Vasantha the answer of your first linked question downloads the binary to `jq`

Answer (score 0):

For Window, here is how it worked for me after long hours of troubleshooting

1. Download jq-win64.exe
2. Reneame jq-win64.exe to jq
3. Copy jq file to C:Program Files\Git\Bin
   4 Search for Environment Variables from your windows. Under "System Variables", find the variable named "Path" and select it, then click "Edit". Click "New" and add the path to the directory where jq is extracted (e.g., C:\Program Files\Git\Bin) and press ok and close the environment variable window.
4. Close and reopen your Command Prompt, and press jq --version
5. hope this helps